# How to convert array to object in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, object

I have this sample data

```js
let data = [{
    id: 1,
    info: [
      'Optical',
      'Drive'
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    info: [
      'Paper',
      'Binder'
    ]
  }
];
```

I want to convert the array in data.info to object and assign 2 key/value pairs, first key is name with value from data.info and 2nd key is the length of data.info string. The result would be something like this:

```js
let data = [{
    id: 1,
    info: [{
        name: 'Optical',
        length: 7
      },
      {
        name: 'Drive',
        length: 5
      },
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    info: [{
        name: 'Paper',
        length: 5
      },
      {
        name: 'Binder',
        length: 6
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

Here's what I've tried so far

```js
const getLength = (str) => (str.length)

const addLength = (str) => {
  try {
    let newObj = {};
    newObj.name = str;
    newObj.length = getLength(str);
    return newObj;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
}

const mapedData = data.map((object) => {
  object.info.map((str) => (addLength(str)))
})
```

However the result is

```
[ undefined, undefined ]
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: When you use an arrow function with curly braces, the `return` must be explicit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do what you require you can loop through the array, using `map()` to update the `info` array within each element. The part your original logic is missing is that you don't set the response of `addLength()` to the property of the parent object - you just execute the function.

```js
let data = [{id: 1,info: ['Optical','Drive']}, {id: 2,info: ['Paper','Binder']}];

data.forEach(x => {
  x.info = x.info.map(y => ({
    name: y,
    length: y.length
  }))
});

console.log(data);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but why does forEach is usable in this case? Because as far as I know, forEach doesn't return a new array

Comment: Glad to help. You're correct in that `forEach()` doesn't return a new array, I'm using it to amend the properties of the existing parent array, not to create a new one.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it.

```js
const result = data.map(curr => {
  // Calculate new info array
  const info = curr.info.map(item => ({name: item, length: item.length}))
  // Create new object from old object and use the new info
  // to not mutate the original object
  return {...curr, info}
}, [])
```

Answer (score 1):

It is as simple as

```
data.forEach(item => item.info = item.info.map((value) => ({name: value, length: value.length})));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const data = [{
    id: 1,
    info: [
      'Optical',
      'Drive'
    ]
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    info: [
      'Paper',
      'Binder'
    ]
  }
];

console.log(data.map(e => ({
  id: e.id,
  info: e.info.map(i => ({
    name: i,
    length: i.length
  }))
})));
```